# ¿Cómo hago para que se pasen los datos introducidos en un campo de formulario a una tabla?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, vba, variables, ms-access

Soy nueva en este mundillo y ando algo perdida..

Estoy creando una base de datos en Access y he visto que necesito utilizar programación para ciertas cosas. La BBDD tiene las siguientes tablas: Equipos, Familia, Objetos, Destinatarios, Usuarios, Vehículos, Dependencias y Rango. He creado un formulario llamado AltaEquipos en el que se da de alta un nuevo equipo adquirido. Dentro de éste formulario he agregado un cuadro combinado en el que elegir a que tipo de "destinatario" va dirigido el equipo en sí (usuario, vehículo o dependencia), con el msg.box le he dicho que pregunte si quieres dar de alta un nuevo usuario por ejemplo, al darle al sí, te conduce a otro formulario para proceder al alta nueva con los campos: DNI_Usuario, Nombre, Apellido1 y Apellido2. Bajo de éste, he creado un botón en el que dice "Añadir a destinatario". Bien, lo que quiero lograr es que me introduzca en sus tablas pertinentes los datos introducidos en ambos formularios. Sí me introduce el equipo nuevo y el usuario pero no le asigna el destinatario, es decir, en la tabla DESTINATARIOS no me agrega el destinatario con su nuevo equipo agregado.

De momento he probado con una sentencia de SQL que me encontré y es la siguiente:

```
Private Sub GuardarRegistroNuevo_Click()
 If formEmpty Then
    SQL = "INSERT INTO DESTINATARIOS(Usuario)" _
        & "VALUES('" & Me.DNI_Usuario & "') "
    CurrentDb.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError
    
End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Has probado a ejecutar tu sentencia SQL solo con Docmd.RunSQL? https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.docmd.runsql

Comment: Hola @Esei, gracias por tu comentario. Sí lo he probado pero de momento no me ha funcionado y se que es por otras cosas que no estoy introduciendo correctamente. Todo esto es nuevo para mí y voy dando palos de ciego a todas horas.